# Popup popping up under div html, svelte, tailwind css

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to make a website using svelte and tailwind. I made a little popup that pops up when you hover over the home icon. But when I later added a div it pops up under the div and does not show fully. How do I fix this?
Code:
Div that popup goes under:  (is in seprate svelte component and is imported in index.svelte.)

```
<div class="fixed ml-15 mb-auto w-screen h-10 bg-gray-700">
<h1 class="text-center text-white font-extrabold text-lg">Welcome.</h1>
</div>
```

Div for the one of the popups and icons: (this one is also in another separate svelte component and is imported in index.svelte.)

```
    <div class="sidebar-icon group">
    <a href="https://github.com/ratinchat" target="_blank">
        <DiGithubBadge />
    </a>
    <span class="sidebar-tooltip group-hover:scale-100">Github</span>
</div>
```

Css for popup:

```
.sidebar-tooltip {
    @apply absolute w-auto p-2 m-2 min-w-max left-14 rounded-md shadow-md
    text-white bg-gray-900 
    text-xs font-bold 
    transition-all duration-100 scale-0 origin-left;
}
```

Helpfull images:

[No popups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGHp3.png)

[With popups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvVkw.png)

The home button popup is hidden under the topbar div.
How can I make it so that the popup (also named tooltip.) pops above the div instead of below. (specifically the home but what if I wanted to make more divs under?) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the document order of the elements is off, you might have to mess with the `z-index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the TailwindCSS class `z-10` or higher to `.sidebar-tooltip`.

Without setting a z-index your elements will be rendered on the same plane as each other, causing overlaps to occur.